# AnyLogic "End of Shift" logic

Tags: anylogic

I have a resource pool that adds units into the population "forklifts". The agents of type Forklift are chosen by other agents and later seized for specific tasks. There is also a schedule for the resource pool.

The problem is that whenever capacity decreases, forklifts units that are moving in the model (but not seized yet) are halted because they are no longer active. Is there a way to customize the choice of resources for the "end of shift". I cannot find anything in Help or online.

Thanks!

I have tried iterating through the resource pool but there is no function I could find to determine whether a unit is active or not. There are boolean functions for idle and busy.

```
agent.unload_forklift = findFirst(forklifts, f->f.in_use == false);
```

There are agents that choose resource agents based on internal variables. Maybe I could iterate through the resource pool instead of the population...

I expect forklifts' capacity to decrease based on a customize signal not randomly.

Comment: What is the difference between 'seized' and 'moving' and 'chosen' forklifts?

Comment: I tried to do something to help you but i'm not sure what you want... is this what you want? : if a resource gets to the end of the shift, you want to decide if that resource actually ends the shift of if it continues another shift? Or will it stop working its shift a bit later? Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Felipe This is exactly want I want to achieve. Let's say that From a population 20 forklifts from 16 are active in the pool. At a given time the schedule changes and only 12 are active. I want to be able to customize the choice of agents from the population that will go through the end of shift because some of them may be "chosen" already.

Comment: @Simon.S.A. they are all moving resources. They are seized by a variety of blocks but chosen prior to any tasks. The selection goes agent to agent wile the seizing goes agent to resource pool.